# ui-dahow to display future date as selected in jquery ui-date picker

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui

I have downloaded jquery ui-date picker and implemented in my php web site. When I click on the date picker textbox it shows current date as selected. I need to display future date (current date+2) as select default

Is it possible?

See my code

```
$(function (){

                // Datepicker
                $('#requTravel').datepicker({
                    inline: true,
                    minDate: 0  

                });

                //hover states on the static widgets
                $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                );

            });
```

Does anyone know this?

i have one more doubt. i have two calander. when i select a date from first calander say(1/07/2012) then my second calander will show 03/07/2012. ie date from the first calander +2  Is it possible?
Please reply

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The minDate option accepts a few formats: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate

http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/5GxcZ/5/

```
// Not Allowed to select before current date, default is 2 days from now
$('#requTravel').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    minDate: +2,
    defaultDate: +2
});

// Allowed to select before current date, default is 2 days from now
$('#requTravel2').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    defaultDate: +2
});

​
```

Comment: You can also just say: defaultDate: '+2'. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Comment: That's more likely an easier solution. I have changed my answer and linked to the docs :)